# TypeError: botGuilds.find is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

**This code is for an express website for my discord bot I need it to catch the mutual guilds but it's giving this error:**

```
TypeError: botGuilds.find is not a function
    at C:\Users\não te interessa\Desktop\projetos\bot\backend\utils\utils.js:3:56
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at Proxy.methods.<computed> (C:\Users\não te interessa\Desktop\projetos\bot\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\array\methods\index.js:956:24)
    at getMutualGuilds (C:\Users\não te interessa\Desktop\projetos\bot\backend\utils\utils.js:3:28)
    at C:\Users\não te interessa\Desktop\projetos\bot\backend\routes\discord.js:11:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

**which uses getMutualGuilds:**

```js
const router = require("express").Router()
const { getBotGuilds } = require("../utils/api")
const { getMutualGuilds } = require("../utils/utils")

const User = require('../database/schemas/Users')
router.get('/guilds', async (req, res) => {
    const guilds = await getBotGuilds();
    const user = await User.findOne({ discordId: req.user.discordId });
    if (user) {
        const userGuilds = user.get('guilds');
        const mutualguilds = await getMutualGuilds(userGuilds, guilds);
        res.send(mutualguilds);
    }
});

module.exports = router
```

**getMutualGuilds code:**

```
function getMutualGuilds(userGuilds, botGuilds) {
    return userGuilds.filter((guild) => botGuilds.find((botGuild) => (botGuild.id === guild.id) && (guild.permissions & 0x20) === 0x20))
}
    
module.exports = { getMutualGuilds }
```

Comment: log `botGuilds` content and add it to Q.

Comment: yep, it's missing the botGuilds code...add please

Answer (score 0):

**code of botGuilds:**

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const TOKEN = "token of my bot";

async function getBotGuilds() {
    const response = await fetch('http://discord.com/api/v8/users/@me/guilds', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            Authorization: `Bot ${TOKEN}`
        }
    })
    return response.json()
}

module.exports = { getBotGuilds }
```